Getting Started with PrimeVue?
I am trying to get started with PrimeVue so I was following the instructions on their website (install PrimeVue).
I ran through the following steps:
npm create vue@latest
npm install
npm run dev
npm install primevue
npm install primeicons
npm install @primevue/themes  (not sure why the '@')

Updated the main.js file to the following:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import 'primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css';
import 'primevue/resources/primevue.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';

import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext';
import Button from 'primevue/button';
import Toast from 'primevue/toast';

createApp(App).use(PrimeVue).mount('#app')

When trying to run it, I get the following error:
Failed to resolve import "@primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css" from "src/main.js". Does the file exist?

I checked the whole directory and was not able to locate two of the following files:
'primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css';
'primevue/resources/primevue.css';
What am I missing?
Note: I did purchase the product and received the .zip file but trying to run 'npm install <primevue .zip file>' got errors.
Thank you

are you upgrading from v3 or using old docs?  the lara-light-blue theme no longer exists, and there is no theme.css import either.  follow relevant section of the v4 documentation on how to import theme.  available theme presets are "aura", "lara" and "nora"

I was following 'Getting Started with PrimeVue and Create Vue' by Cagatay Civici on Youtube.  It's one year old though.  I think you provided a better reference and its video by the same author seems to be up-to-date so I will follow that.  Thank.

@yoduh, I followed the instructions from your reference and everything worked so I am good.  Thank you very much!
